# Another Simple Math Problem? Really?

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking, calculation-puzzle

Yup, I'm adding yet another Simple Math Problem to the recent trend.
Here ya go!

**Given that:**
$$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
\begin{array}{c}
1-1=0\\
1+1=2\\
1+6=7\\
2+5=7\\
5+1=6\\
6-5=1\\
9-7=2
\end{array}&~~~&
\begin{array}{c}
1+3=5\\
2+2=5\\
2+3=6\\
3-1=3\\
4+2=7\\
6+0=7\\~
\end{array}&~~~&
\begin{array}{c}
4-1=2\\
4+1=4\\
8-4=3\\
8+0=7\\~\\~\\~
\end{array}&~~~&
\begin{array}{c}
1+2=6\\
5+5=5\\
7+1=3\\
8-7=4\\~\\~\\~
\end{array}
\end{array}
\\~\\$$

**What is $\bf{3+3 ?}$**

Comment: Everyone has gotten into the craze... now we just need Gareth

Comment: The arrangement just makes my head scream from the obvious patterns there :)

Comment: I wonder what would happen if I just answered ‘6’ :P

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil without an explanation it’d get flagged :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The calculations are made by

> considering the digits on a 7-segment display, adding or subtracting the lit segments as appropriate, then counting the number of lit segments in the result. 
>  
>  Edit: I may have been a bit vague above. Think of "adding" as overlaying the two digits, and "subtracting" as the second digit masking the first. In the case of addition, this is different from adding the number of lit segments for each digits, as there may be some overlap between them.

Therefore, 3 + 3 is

> 5

Comment: No matter how I think of this, I can't seem to get it to work... 3 has 5 segments, so that gives 10, which in turn gives 8 segments, no? (sorry, no spoilers in comments...)

Comment: @Lolgast I guess I didn't really explain it well. I've updated my answer, hopefully it's a bit clearer.

Comment: Ah I think I got it now. However, 9-7=2 doesn't seem to fit? Shouldn't it be 9-7=3? (Unless it's considered 9+9=5, which doesn't quite match the 9+9=6 what I was expecting...)

Comment: @Lolgast I assume the 9 here is the version without the bottom segment lit up.

Comment: I even thought of 7-segment; in fact that was pretty much the only thing I tried. If only I'd done it with pen and paper instead! +1